# How to print z3 solver results print(s.model()) in order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, z3, z3py

Suppose I have a list of 10 variables

```
v = [Real('v_%s' % (i+1)) for i in range(10)]
```

and I want to add a simple constraint like this

```
s = Solver()
for i in range(10):
    s.add(v[i] == i)
if s.check() == sat:
    print(s.model())
```

So a satisfying model is `v_1 = 0, v_2 = 1 .... v_10 = 9`. However the output of `print(s.model())` is totoally unordered which makes me confused when I have lots of variables in a bigger model. For this example, the output of my computer is `v_5, v_7, v_4, v_2, v_1, v_3, v_6, v_8, v_9, v_10`, but I want to ouput the variables of this model in order like `v_1, v_2, ..., v_10`. Can anyone tell me does z3Py have this kind of function or not? Thanks!

Comment: did you try `print(sorted(s.model()))`? don't know about z3 - just a hunch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn the model into a list and sort it in any way you like:

```
from z3 import *

v = [Real('v_%s' % (i+1)) for i in range(10)]

s = Solver()
for i in range(10):
    s.add(v[i] == i)
if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    print (sorted ([(d, m[d]) for d in m], key = lambda x: str(x[0])))
```

This prints:

```
[(v_1, 0), (v_10, 9), (v_2, 1), (v_3, 2), (v_4, 3), (v_5, 4), (v_6, 5), (v_7, 6), (v_8, 7), (v_9, 8)]
```

Note that the names are sorted lexicographically, hence `v_10` comes after `v_1` and before `v_2`. If you want `v_10` to come at the end, you can do further processing as it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with a vector like an IntVector, you can call the element on the `i` position with `m[v[i]]` where `m` is the model, `v` is the vector and `i` is desidered position:

```
v = IntVector('v', 10)

for i in range(10):
    s.add(v[i] == i)

s = Solver()
if (s.check()):
    m = s.model()

    for i in range(10):
        print(m[v[i]])
```

It will not print the **i**-element on the model, but the correct element in the original position.

In your case you can do the same thing:

```
v = [Real('v_%s' % (i+1)) for i in range(10)]

for i in range(10):
    s.add(v[i] == i)

s = Solver()
if (s.check()):
    m = s.model()

    for i in range(10):
        print(m[v[i]])
```