# How do I arrange the values in the model generated by Z3 in an ascending order?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I am using Z3 to generate an optimized schedule. After checking for satisfiability, I generate the model and store it into a text file. But, I observed that Z3 doesn't really arrange the values in the model in any order. Is there a way to make Z3 arrange them in an ascending order?

This is one of the variable values that it has generated.

[image]

Is there a way to make this ascending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Essentially repeating the answer from: [How to print z3 solver results print(s.model()) in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100801/how-to-print-z3-solver-results-prints-model-in-order/52101306#52101306))

You can turn the model into a list and sort it in any way you like. Here's an example:

```
from z3 import *

v = [Real('v_%s' % (i+1)) for i in range(10)]

s = Solver()
for i in range(10):
    s.add(v[i] == i)
if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    print (sorted ([(d, m[d]) for d in m], key = lambda x: str(x[0])))
```

This prints:

```
[(v_1, 0), (v_10, 9), (v_2, 1), (v_3, 2), (v_4, 3), (v_5, 4), (v_6, 5), (v_7, 6), (v_8, 7), (v_9, 8)]
```

Note that the names are sorted lexicographically, hence `v_10` comes after `v_1` and before `v_2`. If you want `v_10` to come at the end, you can do further processing as it fits your needs.

In your case, looks like `car` is either an array-value, or an uninterpreted function. For that specific case, you'll have to query the indices you're interested in separately and collect them in a data-structure of your own to display them in the order you like. Long story short, z3 will give you the values, but how you "present" them is up to you. (If you get stuck, please post what you've tried with an example that others can replicate to help you further.)

Comment: Is there any such simple way to do this in cpp?

Comment: @GermanShepherd Sure. This sort of thing is possible in all languages that z3 has an interface to. What have you tried? Feel free to ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks @alias. Yes, I could do it in cpp.