# How to retrieve the obtained solution in array order when using arrays of BitVec in z3py?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I'm trying to solve a problem using the Array type in z3.
Because I need to use BitVec type I declared the array as :

```
numbers = [BitVec(chr(i), 8) for i in range(0, 4)]
```

And then :

```
s = Solver()
s.add(numbers[0] == 100)
s.add(numbers[1] == numbers[0] + 2)
s.add(numbers[3] == numbers[1] + numbers[0])
s.add(numbers[2] == numbers[1] - 4)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

Output :

```
sat
[ = 98,  = 202,  = 102,  = 100]
```

However it doesn't print in order  the results, Is there a way to print them in order?

Example:

```
[ = 100, = 102, = 98, = 202 ]
```

I have another doubt too. Is there a way to set a limit to the frequencies of a number:

```
numbers = [BitVec(chr(i), 8) for i in range(0, 4)]

s = Solver()
s.add(numbers[0] == 100)
s.add(numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[2] == 200)
s.add(collections.Counter(numbers)[100] == 1) # something like that
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

To set that number 100 must be present only in numbers[0].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print z3 solver results print(s.model()) in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100801/how-to-print-z3-solver-results-prints-model-in-order)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100801/how-to-print-z3-solver-results-prints-model-in-order for your first question. It's always best to ask different questions in different threads on stack-overflow. For frequencies: You'll need to count explicitly and assert a Pb constraint on it.

Comment: How can I implement a counter and assert the constraint on it?

Comment: What have you tried? Please formulate it as a separate question and show us what you tried and where it went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I first propose to give some readable names to the variables. `chr(i) for i in range(0, 4)` are 4 unprintable characters. Better use `chr(i+48)` for digits 0..9 or `chr(i+65)` for letters A..Z

The simplest way to print your result in the same order as the array is just: `print ([s.model[n].as_long() for n in numbers])`.

For your second question, I propose to use Z3's `Sum` function. For example:

```
numbers = [BitVec('N'+chr(i+48), 8) for i in range(0, 4)]
s = Solver()
s.add(numbers[0] == 100)
s.add(numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[2] == 200)
s.add(Sum([If(n == 100, 1, 0) for n in numbers]) == 1)
print(s.check())
m = s.model()
print (m)
print ([m[n].as_long() for n in numbers])
```

Which outputs (in my test case):

```
sat
[N3 = 116, N1 = 106, N0 = 100, N2 = 250]
[100, 106, 250, 116]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used in the end `numbers = [BitVec('{:2}'.format(i), 8) for i in range(32)]`,
end I sorted the value when the model was ready with:
 `
m = s.model();
model = sorted([(d, m[d]) for d in m], key = lambda x: str(x[0]))
`